# How to make sidenav increase/decrease in height, to always fill the entire webpage

Tags: javascript, html, height

I've been trying to make a website that has a header(on top), sidenav(to the left) & the main content of the website. Now here is an example of the layout

https://jsfiddle.net/qdza4bxc/1/

Now, after learning a little JavaScript, i made a function that increases/decreases the sidenav's top-padding when the page is scrolled, here is the exapmle:

https://jsfiddle.net/4vtuq6m8/

but this leaves behind a big gap on top, inside the sidenav. So i was wondering how w3school have done this, when you scroll down their page: https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp you can see that when you scroll down their website, the sidebar's height and content Always stays in perfect place.

I would love if anyone has a solution to this!

Comment: Side menu on w3school uses position: fixed top: 0 left: 0 height: 100vh overflow: scroll... or some small variation of that.. Didn't look but that's just my guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var header = document.querySelector('header');
var headerHeight = header.offsetHeight;
var sidebar = document.querySelector('#sidebar');

document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  // Check how many pixels have been scrolled
  var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  // offset should never be higher than the header
  scrollTop = scrollTop > headerHeight ? headerHeight : scrollTop;
  // Calculate the final offset to apply to the height
  var offsetTop = headerHeight - scrollTop;

  sidebar.style.height = 'calc(100% - ' + offsetTop + 'px)';
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: indianred;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 20%;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  float: left;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#sidebar h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div id="sidebar">
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Hi there</h2>
  <h2>Soon done</h2>
  <h2>Done!</h2>
</div>
<section>
  <h1>Main Content</h1>
  <p>This is just some text that i put inn to make this look some what of a website</p>
  <h2>Next Section</h2>
  <p>This is just some text that i put inn to make this look some what of a website</p>
  <h1>Main Content</h1>
  <p>This is just some text that i put inn to make this look some what of a website</p>
  <h2>Next Section</h2>
  <p>This is just some text that i put inn to make this look some what of a website</p>
  <h1>Main Content</h1>
  <p>This is just some text that i put inn to make this look some what of a website</p>
  <h2>Next Section</h2>
  <p>This is just some text that i put inn to make this look some what of a website</p>
  <h1>Main Content</h1>
  <p>This is just some text that i put inn to make this look some what of a website</p>
  <h2>Next Section</h2>
  <p>This is just some text that i put inn to make this look some what of a website</p>
  <h1>Main Content</h1>
  <p>This is just some text that i put inn to make this look some what of a website</p>
  <h2>Next Section</h2>
  <p>This is just some text that i put inn to make this look some what of a website</p>
  <h1>Main Content</h1>
  <p>This is just some text that i put inn to make this look some what of a website</p>
  <h2>Next Section</h2>
  <p>This is just some text that i put inn to make this look some what of a website</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi! this solved my problem, but i would never have figured this out on my own, especially not that last "js" statement. Is this how you would write your code on your own, or is there a less advanced way you might know of?

Comment: Hey @SimenPedersen, I tried to find a simple solution according to your primary implementation, I don't think this is advanced, just a little bit of logic, but if you follow line by line, it's quite easy, let me know if there is anything you don't understand ;)

Comment: Okey, thanks for helping and trying a simpler solution! I guess the only part i didn't understand was that you could use the calc() extenction from css in a js string :)

Comment: It's exactly what you use in your CSS file `height: calc(100% - 100px)`, but instead of having a hardcoded value of `100px`, it's calculating it on scroll event to check how much of the height of the header is in the viewport.